# How to count active customers using start and end date in Power-BI?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop

Newbie here to Power-BI. I have a project where I need to count the number of active customers per month based on the Start_date and exit_date. There are some customers that do not yet have an exit date as they are still active/ haven't yet exited.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is count the customers that have no exit date (active customers), this worked for me:

```
CountActive = COUNTBLANK('your table'[EXIT_DATE])
```

If you want to show the active customers based on the start date you can simply use a slicer with START_DATE. The measure will automatically update the count of active customers.

If you want to show the customers that already exited (non active customers) you could do the following:

```
CountNonBlank = COUNTROWS('your table') - COUNTBLANK('your table'[END_DATE])
```

Again, just simply add a slicer to show count depending on start date.

Hope this helps